# Snowflake Node Driver exceeds lambda memory when querying large view even if requested results is small

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have an AWS lambda running on NodeJS 18 that is querying a Snowflake instance. It works great on a dozen or so different views on tables with millions of rows each across three databases, but on one table on one database it exceeds the allocated 3008 MB of memory each time, even though the query is restricting the results pretty significantly.

For instance, even on:

```
SELECT LEFT(Complaint.Text, 100), COUNT(DISTINCT Patient.Key) as PatientCount 
FROM Complaint 
INNER JOIN Patient on Complaint.Key = Patient.Key 
WHERE IFNULL(Complaint, '') <> '' GROUP BY Complaint.Text 
ORDER BY Complaint.Text ASC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

It's giving a signal killed memory exceeded.

I've tried both a standard query execution, and streaming with streamResults true in both the connection object and the object parameter for the execute method with the same results. I've also added the rowStreamHighWaterMark with a value of 5 to the connection object with no change in outcome.

Comment: what table does the `complaint` column come from? and if you are thinking it is the whole row, given that table is the left side of the left join, it will not ever be a failure to join. This SQL reads very strange to me.

Answer (score 0):

so the WHERE clause COMPLAINT that compared to an empty string does not name what table it comes from.

```
with complaint(key, text) as (
    select * from values
        (1, 'text 1'),
        (2, 'text 2'),
        (3, '')
), patient(key) as (
    select * from values
        (1)
)
SELECT 
    LEFT(Complaint.Text, 100), 
    COUNT(DISTINCT Patient.Key) as PatientCount 
FROM Complaint 
INNER JOIN Patient 
    on Complaint.Key = Patient.Key 
WHERE IFNULL(Complaint, '') <> '' 
GROUP BY Complaint.Text 
ORDER BY Complaint.Text ASC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

and it is not a value, "whole row" alias:

[image]

so it either comes from the `complaint`, or `patient` table.

Lukasz's simplification is incorrect:

```
with complaint(key, text, complaint) as (
    select * from values
        (1, 'text 1', 'com 1'),
        (2, 'text 2', '' ),
        (3, 'text 3', null)
), patient(key) as (
    select * from values
        (1),
        (2),
        (3)
)
SELECT 
    LEFT(Complaint.Text, 100), 
    Complaint
    --COUNT(DISTINCT Patient.Key) as PatientCount 
    ,IFNULL(Complaint, '') <> '' as org_filter
    ,Complaint IS NOT NULL as wrong_filter
FROM Complaint 
INNER JOIN Patient 
    on Complaint.Key = Patient.Key 
--WHERE IFNULL(Complaint, '') <> '' 
--GROUP BY Complaint.Text 
ORDER BY Complaint.Text ASC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

[image]

But "how this impacts the memory", it should not. I would check the excution history to see what SQL actually is run:

because I get for the original SQL:

```
with complaint(key, text, complaint) as (
    select * from values
        (1, 'text 1', 'com 1'),
        (2, 'text 2', '' ),
        (3, 'text 3', null)
), patient(key) as (
    select * from values
        (1),
        (2),
        (3)
)
SELECT 
    LEFT(Complaint.Text, 100), 
    COUNT(DISTINCT Patient.Key) as PatientCount 
FROM Complaint 
INNER JOIN Patient 
    on Complaint.Key = Patient.Key 
WHERE IFNULL(Complaint, '') <> '' 
GROUP BY Complaint.Text 
ORDER BY Complaint.Text ASC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

[image]

which shows only one row returned; the profile also shows the SQL handed to the server, on the details page:

[image]

for the results to overwhelm your client, I would guess your client code is not giving all the SQL to the server, and is getting too many rows back. Otherwise it just doesn't make sense that 10 rows could take too much ram.

Comment: After closer examination it was crashing on an entirely separate query. Thanks for the  assistance.

Answer (score 0):

After closer examination it was crashing on an entirely separate query, which I rewrote.